# how to prove Euler formula with disconnected graph with k components?

Tags: graph-theory

(8 points) Let $G$ be a graph with an $\mathbb{R_{2}}$-embedding having $f$ faces. Euler’s formula tells us that if $G$ is connected, then $\lvert V \lvert − \lvert E \lvert + f = 2$. What is $\lvert V \lvert − \lvert E \lvert + f$ if $G$ has $k$ connected components? Prove that your answer always works!

How should I approach this? I see all the connected components share 1 common external face, although their vertex and edge sets are distinct.

That implies that $\sum_{i}^{k}\lvert V_{i}\lvert -\sum_{i}^{k}\lvert E_{i}\lvert$ +$\sum_{i}^{k}\lvert f_{i}\lvert - k=2$

and I can induct on $k$ to $k+1$ through induction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the formula should be

$|V|-|E|+f=k+1$

If you consider one component at a time, for component $1\leq i\leq k$, with $|V_i|$ vertices and $|E_i|$ edges and $f_i$ faces, you can simply write

$|V_i|-|E_i|+f_i=2$

Add them all, for all $i$, to get

$\sum_{i}|V_i|-\sum_{i}|E_i|+\sum_{i}f_i=|V|-|E|+\sum_{i}f_i=2\times k$

As you have mentioned, there is only one face that is common between all of them and it has been counted $k$ times. So write the last equation as

$|V|-|E|+\sum_{i}f_i=|V|-|E|+f+(k-1)=2\times k$

Finally

$|V|-|E|+f=k+1$